# How to read and parse a *.vi file and look at its source code in C#

Tags: c#, file, .net-core, io, labview

I have .Vi (virtual instrument) file and I have to read and parse the file and look it and do some logic.

How do I read the .VI file line by line? Is there any plugin we have in dot net?

Comment: Try open it with notepad. If it's readable, you can simply ReadAllLines from the file.

Answer (score 4):

LabVIEW VIs aren't text files. They are saved as binary images of the node and wire objects that make up the diagrams. In order to read a VI, you open it in LabVIEW and use the VI server scripting operations to analyze and modify the block diagrams. There is no "line by line" to read.